# Combine Macro-Enabled Worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine a bunch of different workbooks together. Each workbook has worksheets with it's name being a date and I only want to grab a specific day. Here is my code:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
    Dim sWksName As String
    Dim myValue As Variant
    
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Todays Date 00-00-0000")
    sWksName = myValue
 
    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    Dim mySheetName As String
 
    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then
 
        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0
 
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
 
            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
 
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
 
                sWksName = myValue
    
                wbkSrcBook.Sheets(sWksName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            
 
                wbkSrcBook.Close savechanges:=False
 
            Next
 
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
             
            MsgBox "Beep boop. Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets. Have a splendid day!", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
           Else
        MsgBox "You forgot to select any files :/", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
  End Sub
```

For some reason, it is unable to pull all the sheets that happen to be macro-enabled and will only pull the standard excel documents. Could anyone help me to determine why and what can be done to fix this? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: "it is unable to pull all the sheets that happen to be macro-enabled" - what exactly happens when you run your code with macro-enabled files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it depends on the type of file, it is more likely that there is no correspondence between the format of the inserted date and the name of the sheet.
Try like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineWorkbooks()

    Dim fnameList As Variant, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles As Integer, countSheets As Integer
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim sWksName As String
    
    sWksName = InputBox("Enter Todays Date 00-00-0000")
    If IsDate(sWksName) Then
        fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
        If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then
            If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
                countFiles = 0
                countSheets = 0
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                    countFiles = countFiles + 1
                    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
                        For Each Sh In .Worksheets
                            If IsDate(Sh.Name) Then
                                If CDate(sWksName) = CDate(Sh.Name) Then
                                    Sh.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next Sh
                        .Close savechanges:=False
                    End With
                Next fnameCurFile
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                MsgBox "Beep boop. Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets. Have a splendid day!", Title:="Merge Excel files"
            End If
               Else
            MsgBox "You forgot to select any files :/", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect date; operation canceled.", vbCritical, "ERROR"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much much! You don't know what a lifesaver this is.